# Help finding a YouTube channel for Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I remember watching a youtube playlist on a video about equation of a plane and about vectors in 3D. The video was fully animated in 3D and had good sound effects too. I feel like it had a clock mascot somewhere but I could be wrong. The video was narrated by a professor.

Comment: If it had been a "pi" mascot instead of a "clock" mascot, it almost certainly would have been a 3Blue1Brown video. Are you sure it wasn't that? https://www.3blue1brown.com/topics/linear-algebra

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to provide this question with an answer, as my suggestion was confirmed in the comments, the Youtube playlist you're looking for is Robert Ghrist's [Calculus Blue Volume 1](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8erL0pXF3JYm7VaTdKDaWc8Q3FuP8Sa7&si=LUJdBDbwshsPzJNQ) on vectors and matrices.

(Post made Community wiki.)